# How to hide some controls in the usercontrol conditionally from parent page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a aspx page which has five panels. Each panel has a usercontrol in it. The user controls on all the five panels are the same. The user control in the first panel is to gather data for primary members and the rest are used for secondary members. I use ">" and "<" custom buttons to move from one panel to another. Whenever I move from the primary panel to secondary I wan to hide two textboxes in the usercontrol. When they move back to the primary panel, those textboxes should reappear. Since the buttons are in the parent page, please let me know how to do it. I believe creating an event in the usercontrol and accessing it from parent page may work. But not sure how to do it. Or please let me know any other methods.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, the buttons `>` and `<` are in the page to advance to the next/previous control. Then you just have to handle their click event in the page and switch visibility of the UserControls.

Answer (score 1):

You need not create an event in the user controls for this.

All that you need is to create a public property on the user control, that you can set when you use the user control.

Since you have not provided any code, I will just give a sample.

```
public partial class MyWidget: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private bool showPrimary;
    public bool ShowPrimary
    {
        get { return showPrimary; }
        set 
        {
            showPrimary = value;
            txtPK1.Visible = value;
            txtPK2.Visible = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you set it when you call it as follows:

```
Main Panel:
<uc1:MyWidget ID="MyWidget1" ShowPrimary="true" runat="server" />

Secondary Panel:
<uc1:MyWidget ID="MyWidget1" ShowPrimary="false" runat="server" />
```

Comment: This answer helped me to achieve my functionality to show hide button on user control

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, the buttons `>` and `<` are in the page to advance to the next/previous control. Then you just have to handle their click event in the page and switch visibility of the UserControls.

If you don't know how to control visibility of controls inside of UserControls from the page:

- Use properties in the `UserControl`, for example `PrimaryMode`. There you can hide/show the `TextBoxes` accordingly. You can call these properties from the page. `PrimaryMode` could be of type `bool` or a custom enum type(if you want to provide multiple display-modes).